# "Que yo sepa" y otras expresiones en su función sintáctica

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

¿Se puede definir *que yo sepa*, *la verdad sea dicha* y *Dios no lo quisiera* como un paréntesis desde el punto de vista sintáctico? ¿O me equivoco?

> 1. ***Que yo sepa***, el Barcelona tiene veinte internacionales de varios países.
> 2. *Se puso a marcar los pasos (**la verdad sea dicha**, haciéndolos algo cortos).*
> 3. *Debía evitar hacer cualquier ruido, porque si lo hacía, **Dios no lo quisiera**, su mujer se asustaría.*

Comment: "La verdad sea dicha" y "Dios no lo quisiera" son expresiones incorrectas de por sí.

Comment: "la verdad sea dicha" si que es correcta sintácticamente, pero no es una expresión que se use, al menos en España.

Comment: @amchacon: sí, a mí también me parecen desafortunadas... sobretodo „Dios no lo quisiera“ jajaja : ) en realidad es una traducción, creo que el idioma original es ruso

Comment: Es que la expresión correcta es "Dios no lo **quiera**".

Comment: Puede que se deba a diferencias regionales, pero a mí no me suena mal ninguna de las tres (en español de Chile). En el caso de "Dios no lo quisiera" hay narración de estilo indirecto libre, y la conjugación del subjuntivo se ajusta forzadamente. Me parece que es correcto y funciona bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de oraciones se comenta en el [epígrafe 31.1q](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OGSRLwlQPaFiXkFw) de la Nueva Gramática Española:

> Una subordinada sustantiva puede interpretarse a la manera de un tópico inicial con valor cercano al condicional [...]. En este uso de las subordinadas sustantivas (en un sentido algo laxo del término *subordinada*), las oraciones alternan con otros grupos sintácticos que expresan puntos de vista del hablante, como *por lo que yo sé, hasta donde recuerdo, según mis informaciones*, etc. Se ha señalado repetidamente que el concepto de *oración subordinada* se aplica a estas construcciones de manera impropia.

Por su parte, [los paréntesis](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UnoZggFgORpxDlia) sirven

> [...] para insertar en un enunciado una información complementaria o aclaratoria.

Entre otras cosas, sirven para aislar incisos, elementos suplementarios que aportan precisiones, ampliaciones, rectificaciones o circunstancias a lo dicho.

Poniendo el caso de tus ejemplos, las frases quedarían perfectamente válidas de esta forma:

- El Barcelona tiene veinte internacionales de varios países (que yo sepa).
- Se puso a marcar los pasos, haciéndolos algo cortos (la verdad sea dicha).
- Debía evitar hacer cualquier ruido, porque si lo hacía (Dios no lo quisiera) su mujer se asustaría.

Así expresadas, las frases siguen manteniendo su sentido original incluso si eliminamos los paréntesis, ya que sólo aportan una opinión personal del que habla.